# ES2015+ way to efficiently transform array of objects into grouped hashmap with array of objects as value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find an elegant and efficient way to convert an array of objects into an object indexed by a key (in this instance "groupByThisKey"). A hashmap I believe it's called.

I was able to come up with a primitive version

Explained with some data below:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "two",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "three",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "four",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
  }
];

const groupedByKey = {};

arr.map(obj => {
  if (groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey])
    groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey].push(obj)
  else
    groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey] = [obj]
});

console.log(groupedByKey)
```

It does give the desidered output:

```
{
  groupA: [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "one",
     groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
   },
   {
     id: 4,
     name: "four",
     groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
   }
  ],
  groupB: [
   {
     id: 2,
     name: "two",
     groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: "three",
     groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
   }
  ]
}
```

But in a rather primitive way. I'd much rather use a shorter and more modern way of doing this, potentially with object.assign or reduce if possible, but can't wrap my head around it, since I need an array of values for each key.

I was able to find many examples which all seemed to work for use cases where you only have one value per key, but in my case I would need an **array of objects grouped by that key**, so the examples I found would only take the latest. Here's an example:

```
const hash = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(s => ({[s.key]: s.value})));
```

Comment: Your code is very readable and it looks fine as it is. You could probably use `reduce` but that's not much of an improvement

Comment: This may be a good fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you implemented is pretty correct, let me just remove the side-effects by using a reducer:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "two",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "three",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "four",
    groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
  }
];

console.log(arr.reduce((groupedByKey,obj) => {
  if (groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey])
    groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey].push(obj)
  else
    groupedByKey[obj.groupByThisKey] = [obj]
    
  return groupedByKey;
}, {}));
```

Here you go the most fp-ish way of writing it. Not really performat, the next version below (after this) will have better performance because it's not new creating objects or arrays on very iteration.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "one",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "two",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "three",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "four",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
    }
];

console.log(arr.reduce(
    (groups, x) => 
        ({ 
            ...groups, 
            [x.groupByThisKey]: [
                ...(groups[x.groupByThisKey] || []),
                x
            ]
        })
    , {}
))
```

Simpler version that has the same logic as above:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "one",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "two",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "three",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupB'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "four",
        groupByThisKey: 'groupA'
    }
];

console.log(arr.reduce(
    (groups, x) => {
        let key = x.groupByThisKey;
        
        if (groups[key] === undefined)
            groups[key] = [];
            
        groups[key].push(x);
        
        return groups;
    }, {}
))
```

Comment: Thank you alot for this. Even better than the answer I was hoping for! Between version 1 and 3, what would you recommend as the best?

Comment: @Dac0d3r You're welcome! Actually both 1 and 3 are kinda the same, since version 1 is originally written by you so I suggest going with that :) (I just added a little reducer) Also if you think I justify the question, you should consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I have 2 great answers. Yours is somewhat closer to what I thought I was looking for, single-statement and using reduce. On the other hand if @Bergi is right about the performance penalty of mutating `group`, then maybe it's better to just accept and use a map and wrap it in a function. I mean, if it is the most performant solution. So... a bit in doubt which of the 2 great answers offers the best solution for the given problem :-)

Comment: @Dac0d3r Well then you also have an option of keeping it unaccepted, but better you make a choice! Btw I hope you know you can also use `Map` in the reducer solution too. Meaning that `group` could be a `Map` instead of `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it all boils down to elegancy vs performance. If reduce is indeed mutating and making copies that makes it execution time slower than the solution proposed by Bergi, I think the best solution would indeed be the more primitive one. Although reduce looks cool and the single-statement thing is awesome, I think it may not be the right use of reduce, if it is slower than Bergi's or mine. But I appreciate your answer alot. Very cool to see how it can be solved with reduce. Very educative! I think I will go for Bergi's and just wrap it in a function :)

Comment: @Dac0d3r Oh no you are confusing things. Reducer is not slow that nor is mutation. What Bergi meant is that my second solution would be slow since it's making copies (as I have written). Bergi's point was that using reducer would make it Non-FP. The first solution has absolutely no performance issues bcoz is is not making copies (even Bergi would agree). When Bergi says "super-inefficient" he's talking about my second solution **not reducers in general** Also welcome! Also please feel free to whatever answer you like, no pressure xD

Answer (score 1):

The modern way would use a `Map`, not an object:

```
const groupedByKey = new Map();
for (const obj of arr) {
  if (!groupedByKey.has(obj.groupByThisKey))
    groupedByKey.set(obj.groupByThisKey, []);
  groupedByKey.get(obj.groupByThisKey).push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping you could do it in a single statement without `const groupedByKey` but I guess you can always wrap a function around it.

Comment: @Dac0d3r Yes, wrapping it in a function is the best idea. Of course you could also achieve a single-statement solution by using `reduce`, but given that you're mutating the accumulator I would avoid giving it a functional programming touch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bergi. But if I store the return of the reduce solution (proposed by Devansh J) in a const and console log both arr and newArr (the returned value from the reduce call) it does not seem to have mutated the original arr. So not sure I understand what you're saying, and why this would be the better way?

Comment: @Dac0d3r In FP you are not supposed to mutate the inputs to a function, when you'll use a reducer you'll have to mutate the accumulator thus making it Non-FP. Though in my answer I have written a reducer without mutating the accumulator.

Comment: @Dac0d3r It's not about mutating the `arr`, it's about mutating the `groupedByKey` Map or object (`group` in Devansh's answer). You could get around mutating it by making a copy of it on every step, but that's super-inefficient.